# Doubts for create a Totoloto with functions

Tags: java

Hi Guys i have a problem in my program of Totoloto. I want create a  function for show the six numbers of the key but i can't because in my output show only a one number at end counter position. I make a debug  with System.out.println in inside the function numeDeChaves and appears  all numbers . If try without functions and its work but i want in  function for legible code and learn a little more how to work the  functions.

this is wrong output:

> Quantas chaves pretende gerar? 6
>
> As chaves geradas são:  1ª chave ->  2ª chave ->  3ª chave ->  4ª chave ->  5ª chave ->  6ª chave ->  36

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Totoloto \n");
    System.out.println("Quantas chaves pretende gerar?");

    int numero = Ler.umInt();
    int[] numeroChaves = new int[numero];
    int[] chave = new int[8];

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("As chaves geradas são: ");
    System.out.println(numeroDeChaves(numeroChaves));  
}    
public static int numeroDeChaves(int[] numeroChaves){
    int contador = 1;
    int totalChaves = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numeroChaves.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(contador + "ª chave -> ");
        contador++;
        for (int j = 0; j < numeroChaves.length; j++) {    
            numeroChaves[j] = chaveAleatoria(numeroChaves);
            totalChaves = numeroChaves[j];
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    return totalChaves;  
}
    
public static int chaveAleatoria(int chave[]) {
    int numeroAleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * 43) + 6;
    int ultimoNumero = chave[0] + 1;
    int chaveGerada = 0;
    int contarChaves = 0;
        
    for (int i = 1; i < chave.length; i++) {
        if (chave[i] == chave[i - 1] && ultimoNumero != chave[i - 1]) {
            ultimoNumero = chave[i];
            chave[i] = numeroAleatorio;
        } else {
            chave[i] = numeroAleatorio;
            chaveGerada = chave[i];
            System.out.print("");
        }
    }
    return chaveGerada; 
}
```

Comment: Why do you just generate a random number once in the method but assign it `numero` times? Additionally it's quite hard to read a source code with foreign variable names. There's also a [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/). This might be more useful.

Comment: In method chave aleatória generate one key. Ex 4 5 45 7 34 22 and in method numeroChaves its supposed generated various keys for example if put in input 3 generate 3 keys ex: 3 34 45 3 5 23 and 4 6 34 12 11 2 and 2 4 6 45 4 3

Comment: But why do you assign `numeroAleatorio` to every element of `chave` in `chaveAleatoria`? You have the assignment in both paths of your `if`-statement.

Comment: Because if have a repeated number generate a new key. Because in this program can't have a repeated numbers in key

Comment: Sorry, but this makes no sense at all. You should only assign this number if it doesn't appear in the array. Additionally you have a ridiculous amount of loops in your program. I'm quite sure you can eliminate most of them!

Comment: In the first method I use 2 for because I am asking the user for the key dimension so one reads the rows and the other the columns. Souting the second for the second method will print out the right amount of keys my problem is moving to main. It no longer works.

Comment: I checked the contents of your array and as expected your algorithm isn't working at all. Please rethink it completely. If you use a nested loop you should use both indices!